# Inaccurate time? How to fix it?

Tags: alarm, standby, clock, date-and-time

*Sometimes* the time on my phone (X10 mini pro) is a little late while in sleep mode. I've experienced differences from 1 to 3 hours. My guess is that the clock system component (if there is such a thing in Android) doesn't get enough CPU time for some reason. This is not a big problem yet, since the clock will show the correct time just a few hundred milliseconds after I turn the screen on. The problem starts when I'm in sleep mode too and the phone is supposed to wake me up, because that way I have to wake up first to wake up my phone to wake me up.

So the question is: is there a way to force my phone's clock to always refresh it's time, even in sleep mode?

**Update:**
I think I've found a pattern which might be relevant. Looks like this behaviour never occurs while charging the battery.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't resis the "I'm in sleep mode" part. :)

Comment: I would expect that the clock ticking on modern chip will be separate than the main CPU. I doubt that the problem wasn't because of the clock not getting enough CPU time

Comment: Ok, I changed my guess a little. The clock ticking has to be good for sure, since very shortly after I turn the screen on every application gets to know the correct time.

Comment: I would expect the possibility that the screen is simply not being updated because the display is turned off. Is the Alarm still going off at the correct time though? Or is your alarm going off late as well?

Comment: The alarm is late too.

Comment: @ytg Are you sure? I have the same experience but the alarm is fine, it's just the screen-updating.

Comment: @Matthew Read I had this problem before the 2.1 upgrade for the X10 mini. After that I didn't experience things like that, but I have to say that I charge the batteries at night in most of the cases now, and I don't really care about screen updating. But I'll try to not charge the batteries at night for a week and see what happens.

Comment: @Matthew Read: My experiments shows that the screen updating can be wrong but when the alarm fires it updates almost instantly. And I get the alarm four out of five times, which is better than before, but still not perfect.

Comment: Yeah, you want more than 80% reliability for an alarm.

Comment: updating ROM may be the solution for your problem.

Comment: Do you live near a timezone shift?

Comment: Interesting idea, but actually, no. :)

Comment: Just thought I'd add... I'm experiencing a similar anomaly on my ICS Tablet. When in sleep-mode my tablet will lose minutes (not hours). My tablet is in regular use, so I can lose 2-3 minutes per day - which adds up over a few days! However, turning the screen on does not correct the time. The alarm is also late as noted above. Full power off/on appears to correct the time, as does performing a manual time sync (disable/enable Settings > Date & Time > Automatic date & time). Auto time sync seems to be rather infrequent?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an app called [ClockSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.org.amip.ClockSync&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInJ1Lm9yZy5hbWlwLkNsb2NrU3luYyJd), which fetches time from NTP servers and updates the device's date and time.  Rooted users can make this app to update time at configurable interval.